# getting an exception wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, textbox

I'm getting this exception , i'm trying to change the tex`enter code here`tbox width when the mouse on over the `textbox`

**this is thh exception :**

> Cannot animate the 'Width' property on a
>   'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox' using a
>   'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'. For details see the
>   inner exception.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#248FB3" />
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"/>     
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">

            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="250" >
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard> 
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="250"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

Comment: did you look into the inner exception ? it might help - provide it please.

Comment: the problem was that I had to set the width before I change in the animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set either `Width` on your `TextBox` element or, `From` property on `DoubleAnimation`. When you don't set either, it gets default value of the `Width` property which is `Double.NaN`, so it doesn't know from where to start.